# How to make protoype work inside a function inside a object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

I need help to fix the code in exemplo 3. I cannot sort how to make the prototype to work because of the this reference. I know the this referes to local scope but even creating a var keep=this to pass the reference it fails in the protoype:

```
//exemplo 1
var m1=function(){
    this.a=null;
    this.b=null;
    if (typeof this.fr !== "function") {
        m1.prototype.fr = function (obp) {
          var propriedade;
          for (propriedade in obp) {
        if (obp.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
          this[propriedade]=obp[propriedade];
        }
          }
          return this;                
        }
    }
}

var t2=new m1().fr({"a":"eee"}); //works!
console.log(t2);


//exemplo 2
var m1=function(obp){
    this.a=null;
    this.b=null;
    if (typeof this.fr !== "function") {
        m1.prototype.fr = function () {
          var propriedade;
          for (propriedade in obp) {
        if (obp.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
          this[propriedade]=obp[propriedade];
        }
          }
          return this;                
        }
    }
}

var t2=new m1({"a":"eee"}).fr(); //works!
console.log(t2);

//exemplo 3

var o1={
    m1:function(){
        var m1=this;
        this.a=null;
        this.b=null;
        if (typeof this.fr !== "function") {
            this.prototype.fr = function (obp) { //fails here
              var propriedade;
              for (propriedade in obp) {
                if (obp.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
                  thia[propriedade]=obp[propriedade];
                }
              }
              return this;                
            }
        }
    }
}
var t2=new o1.m1().fr({"a":"eee"}); //fails!
console.log(t2);
```

FIXED based on Karim answer:

```
//exemplo 1
var m1=function(){
    this.a=null;
    this.b=null;
    if (typeof this.fr !== "function") {
        m1.prototype.fr = function (obp) {
          var propriedade;
          for (propriedade in obp) {
        if (obp.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
          this[propriedade]=obp[propriedade];
        }
          }
          return this;                
        }
    }
}

var t1=new m1().fr({"a":"eee"});
console.log(t1);


//exemplo 2
var m2=function(obp){
    this.a=null;
    this.b=null;
    if (typeof this.fr !== "function") {
        m2.prototype.fr = function () {
          var propriedade;
          for (propriedade in obp) {
        if (obp.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
          this[propriedade]=obp[propriedade];
        }
          }
          return this;                
        }
    }
}

var t2=new m2({"a":"eee"}).fr();
console.log(t2);

//exemplo 3

var o1={
    m1:new m1()
}
var t3=o1.m1.fr({"a":"eee"});
console.log(t3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is your code:

```
var o1={
    m1:function(){
        var m1=this;
        this.a=null;
        this.b=null;
        if (typeof this.fr !== "function") {
            this.prototype.fr = function (obp) { //fails here
              var propriedade;
              for (propriedade in obp) {
                if (obp.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
                  thia[propriedade]=obp[propriedade];
                }
              }
              return this;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you're trying to access the `prototype` from the current `this` that inside an object method is the current instance.

But the current instance is an *object literal* (`o1`) and the `prototype` object is meant to be used on *constructor functions* that you don't have in this case.

try creating a constructor function for o1  then inside the if statement refer to the function to set the prototype